# SharePoint 2010 Contributor Permission

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to restrict the Site Actions menu and the Page tab/ribbon from Contributors in SharePoint 2010? We only want the Contributors to click on the green plus signs where it says “Add…” on the site pages.

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? The ribbon includes some great options: creating, alerts, pick views, RSS feed, etc.

Comment: Our managers feel that it offers too much for our users (enough to be dangerous).

Comment: Permissions are carried across the ribbon. If they can only contribute to a list, that's all they'll do to the list. They can't break it or be dangerous, hence permissions... You can look into disabling additional permissions (i.e.  alerting). The button will still appear, it will just be greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

In your .master page, surround desired elements with

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="AddListItems">
  <!-- Site Actions menu in here, also tab/ribbon -->
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

PermissionString is the key attribute there, and there are several [others](http://sympmarc.com/2008/12/31/spsecuritytrimmedcontrol-possible-values-for-permissionsstring/). There isn't a actual "Contribute" value for the attribute so you will need to confirm that "AddListItems" works for you (if you have OOB Permission levels, it should).

Comment: Is there an easier way????

Comment: If you want to have Contribute permissions for users, they will see the Site Actions menu and Ribbbon. That's the functionality of SharePoint, and if you wish to modify that functionality, you need to restrict control visibility somehow. SPSecurityTrimmedControl is made for that purpose. There is no way to configure this using browser, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that there is no out of box way of using "permission levels" for SPSecurityTrimmedControl .  However you can write something that will inherit from the SPSecurityTrimmedControl class and then allow it to use permission levels.  Then you can create your own custom permission levels and then use that to trim stuff out.

take a look at this blog I wrote that goes over this
http://spcrew.com/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=3